# JQuery UI sortable saving with connected lists

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two lists (1 and 2) and I want to update them when an item is moved from one to another.

HTML:

```
<ul class="sortable" id="task-list">
   <li id="listItem_1">Value 1 </li>
   <li id="listItem_2">Value 2 </li>
   <li id="listItem_3">Value 3 </li>
</ul>

<ul class="sortable" id="task-list-two">
   <li id="listItem_4">Value 1 </li>
   <li id="listItem_5">Value 2 </li>
   <li id="listItem_6">Value 3 </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("#task-list, #task-list-two").sortable({ 
   handle : '.handle',
   connectWith: ".sortable" 
   update : function () { 
     var order = $('#task-list').sortable('serialize'); 
     $("#info").load("process-sortable.php?"+order); 
   } 
});
```

But I want to update the list (1 or 2) as well. Do I need to post an additional variable to `process.sortable.php` ?

The foreach I currently have is only for the first list (simplified):

```
$task = nl2br($_POST['task']);
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$position = $_POST['p'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$i = "INSERT INTO tasks VALUES('','$task','$userid','0','$position','$date')";
$doi = mysql_query($i) or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATED FOREACH PHP:

```
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item)
{
    $list = $_GET['list'];
    if($list == "task-list")
    {
        $list = 1;
    }
    if($list == "task-list-two")
    {
        $list = 2;
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE `tasks` SET `position` = $position AND date = '$list' WHERE `id` = $item"; 

    print($sql);
    $dosql = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: If all you're doing is running a serverside script, you probably should'nt be using load() ?

Comment: I do that for retreiving the SQL statement that is posted.

Comment: Where that `list` param came from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just pass the lists id to the PHP page like:

```
$("#info").load("process-sortable.php?"+order+"&list="+$(this).attr('id'));
```

Once on the PHP page, you can make a condition for the list type.

You will also need to change the order variable to account for the different lists:

```
var order = $(this).sortable( "serialize" );
```

Comment: Seems legit. However, I do get this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). 

Update my question with the foreach code.

Comment: That almost works. It updates the items, but not with the right lists. It gives it the list id from wich it came, not to which it goes. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I made a fiddle example to mess with, I am not seeing the problem... though perhaps my example does not take all variables into account.

[My Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gralex07/tfj7s/)

Comment: Thanks, your example made it work. However, I only have a problem when moving items from list 2 to 1, it still sees it as item from list 2 when I drop it as the last item from list 1. How can I stop that?

Comment: Still not 100% sure of the problem, the only thing I could see is that if you move the last item from list 1 to list 2, your update will run but will have blank values for list 1 (because there is no longer any items in list 1.) I updated the example to deal with a blank list.